# Connection-Specific Database Reader Class

Tags: c#, oop, vba, odbc

At my job, most of our data revolves around a single ODBC datasource -- however, we have hundreds of VBA macros that are polluted with thousands of explicit instances of ADODB connection & recordset objects (all connected via the same DSN).

There is quite a bit of code that I'd like to refactor that's currently in the form of:

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

cn.Open "MYDSN"
SQL = "SELECT * FROM [...]"
rs.Open SQL, cn

' utilize rs ...

rs.Close
cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

I'm imagining a reusable class dll, probably written in C#.NET that would provide a simple interface to accomplish the above more concisely.

My question is, how would you set out to design this class?  I'm fairly new to C#, but would like to avoid leaving the same mess behind for the next person.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is working, what do you see as the advantage to your employers?

Comment: Instead of changing the ODBC DSN on every machine that uses these applications, we could change the database connection information in one spot.

Comment: This must be common across those companies that decided that they didn't need local IT and developers (at least a few) to manage standards. I'm in the exact same boat. We run our operations on VBA macros and it kills me. VBA can be good and robust but the learning curve for it is so gentle that most VBA floating around is macro recorded and forum copy pastes. The source is way to accessible. Well, I have nothing constructive to add other than nod and some empathy to your plight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the good old KISS principle - create one static method `CreateRecordset(string SQL)` that reads the DSN from configuration, opens the connection and return the recordset object for the given SQL.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend making anything that has to do with data access static if you have a bunch of sources invoking it simultaneously.  Unless you add some sort of connection management in there yourself that can lead do some pretty awful fireworks.

Comment: The static method would create a new connection each time. Not reuse a single static instance.

Comment: I'm with @Knagis on this one. You are going to be fighting ADO.Net to get it to work like this, pooled connections, garbage Collection and such. Add a VBA method to return a recordset.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Library 5.0 is good place to start.  It has pretty much everything you need built right in.  No need to reinvent the wheel.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664408%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx